# How to get the URL from the DAG in Airflow using templating?

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2

I was trying to send to Slack an alert when the previous task fails but I would like to add the url from the DAG in the text to go easily from slack.

I tried this, but I'm getting an error:

````
    send_slack_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_alert',
        slack_webhook_conn_id="slack_connection",
        message="There is an error\n"
                "DAG name: {{ dag }}\n"
                "Run: {{ run_id }}\n"
                "url: {{ conf.base_url }}/dags/{{ dag.dag_id }}/grid```",
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED
    )
````

Error:

```
'airflow.configuration.AirflowConfigParser object' has no attribute 'base_url'
```

I was looking this doc from airflow
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AirflowConfigParser` has a `get()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7ba27e78812b890f0c7642d78a986fe325ff61c4/airflow/configuration.py#L561) you can use to retrieve Airflow configuration settings. This method can still be used in a Jinja expression.

```py
SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_alert',
        slack_webhook_conn_id="slack_connection",
        message="There is an error\n"
                "DAG name: {{ dag.dag_id }}\n"
                "Run: {{ run_id }}\n"
                "url: {{ conf.get('webserver', 'BASE_URL') }}/dags/{{ dag.dag_id }}/grid",
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED
    )
```

**Rendered Template**
[image]